# How can I update textview text using async.process in Android?

Tags: android

I want to update my text view when ever loop is on `doinbackground() {}` runs. I want to update my text view with the counter of the loop that is running in the background

```
protectedBooleandoInBackground(String...args)
{
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() ) 
    { 
      do {
          publishProgress();
          }
      while( cursor.moveToNext() );
    }
    else {
    }

    try
      {
        if (writer!=null)
           writer.close();
      }
    catch(IOExceptione) 
    {
        Log.w("Test",e.toString());
    }
    end loop
    return null;
}


protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values)
{
    Log.i("test..","ramjit");
}
```

I'm not able to enter my `onProgressUpdate()` method. So how update textview when loop is running on `doinbackground();`

Comment: So can you clarify what the code is doing, not doing, and if you are seeing any errors?

Comment: actually cant able to run onProgressUpdate(String... values) method...

Comment: and how to set text so that it will update?

Comment: Okay so onProgressUpdate never runs.  Is the line in your do/while loop ever being run?

Comment: yes onProgressUpdate never runs and do/while loop is running ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the AsyncTask page - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Your publishProgress may not working as you aren't passing along any values.
Try to call publisherProgress(stringHere)

Then in onProgressUpdate use the data from the values array.  As onProgressUpdate is run on the UI thread it's safe to just update a textview as normal.

Comment: what should be passed through publisherProgress(stringHere) for getting do/while cursor count on onProgressUpdate() ?

Comment: that is dependent on your code and logic.  You pass whatever information you need so in onProgressUpdated you can inform the user.

Comment: can i set the text inside onProgressUpdate() ? means textview.settext("some thing") and it will update accordigly do/while loop in doinbackground() method?

Comment: Yes you can update UI elements inside of onProgressUpdate() as it executes on the UI-Thread.

Comment: 08-02 12:39:46.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 12:39:46.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(884): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
08-02 12:39:46.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(884):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
08-02 12:39:46.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(884):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)

Comment: protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     Log.i("ergwe","ewrtgwetwert");
     TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tview1);
    tv.setText(progress[0]);
       }  then above error is showing

Comment: It looks like from your error the R.id.tview1 does not exist. At least that is what I'm seeing from your log.

Comment: you was trying to put an integer into a text view without first doing String.valueOf()